# How to automatically handle all unhandled php errors in symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.3

Disclaimer:

seems like you guys need some real world example for that. So here it is:

```
file_get_contents($filename);
```

Keep in mind about thread safety and race conditions.

or any other php notice/warning or any kind of recoverable exception.

where either is not defined. And run it in the default `app.php` with all the default symfony v2.3.5 configs - I see

```
Notice: Undefined variable: i in /var/www/.../UIBundle/Controller/DeployController.php on line 57

Call Stack:
    0.0000     629696   1. {main}() /var/www/.../web/app.php:0
```

Which is not what I expect since in the production mode framework should handle everything, log and show a nice 404/500 to a user.

What am I missing and what config parameter should change the behaviour to what I expect?

**UPD**:

this question is about how to handle unhandled php errors so that user didn't see the stacktrace but a proper error page on production. So treat `$i++` and `\bla()` as some unexpected case, a bug.

**UPD 2**:

yes, I'm aware of the `debug` parameter of the `Kernel` class, and personally I don't see switching to

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', true);
                                 ^--- changed from false
```

reasonable, since I need a *real* production environment.

**UPD 3**:

Guys, I'm aware what unit, functional, acceptance and integration tests are for. The question **IS NOT** about testing. The question is: how to handle php errors by symfony2 natively.

**UPD 4**:

The question is about the latest symfony2 branch - 2.3 (or v2.3.5 specifically)

**UPD 5**:

<s>`Debug::enable(null, false);` - could please someone comment a possible negative side effects if I used this in production?</s> --- it doesn't log notices/warnings :-S

Comment: How about checking if it's defined?

Comment: @OptimusCrime: It's about creating a bullet-proof application. I cannot (and no one can) guarantee my code is bug-less, so I need to get the handler working to log everything unexpected. So that user could see a nice error page, not a stack trace.

Comment: I can see that you have a lot rep here, and I guess it makes sense. However, you are not very good at programming if you can't avoid using something like a method or variable that is not defined like that. You can use php.ini to not output notice-errors, but I don't know how to get Symfony to use the default app when that happens. I don't really know if it's possible.

Comment: @OptimusCrime: "You can use php.ini to not output notice-errors" --- it's not the case. I don't want to pretend there is no issue, I want to log it. "However, you are not very good at programming if you can't avoid using something like a method or variable that is not defined like that" --- anyone makes mistakes. Never say never.

Comment: Such mistakes are meant to be eliminated on dev environment with proper unit testing. Using settings in php.ini you can sill log all errors and let symfony handle nice error page without showing more details. Other way is to define your own error handler that will take care of logging and displaying error page.

Comment: @dev-null-dweller: unit testing only guarantees that your tests pass, but it doesn't guarantee that your code is 100% error free. "and let symfony handle nice error page without showing more details" --- how? As I said - at the moment I see a notice message and a stack trace.

Comment: Do these notices, etc., occur even after creating an event listener for symfony's `kernel.exception` with gentler alerts to the user?

Comment: @geoB: I actually found that it's a confirmed "bug": https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/6474#issuecomment-17041891